# How to force a specific user in the Author textfield in Rules Create Entity

Tags: 7, rules

I created a rule which creates an entity. I would like that every created entity has a specific author.

for the moment, it's look like I can only put the currently logged-in user in that textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to fetch a user entity first. There's an action called fetch entity by id, which will allow you to select user as type and specify the user id.

[image]

At the bottom you can assign label and machine name for the variable that will be made available.

[image]

make sure to do the fetching before creating the new entity, else this variable won't be available.

[image]